# How to put setText() in JTextArea with for loop?

Tags: for-loop, jtextarea, windowbuilder

So I am making this program(WindowBuilder). The user puts a word in the textField and in the other textField how many times he wants it to be repeated in the JTextArea.

private class BtnRepeterActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

```
    String texte = textField.getText();

    for (int i = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()); i >0; i++){
        texte = texte + "\n";
    }
    textArea.setText(texte); 

    }
```

This code makes the program freeze whenever I click on my button. I tried putting "return" but that puts an error. I do not know what to do next.

EDIT**: Putting i-- instead of i++ puts my text in the textArea. 
But it doesn't want to repeat the word with the number I provide in the second textField.
[This image shows the program. When I type a number in the Repetition textField, I want the text to repeat times the number I provided. So if I type 4, it should repeat 4 times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuEFD.png)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Try i-- instead of i++. Basically you set i to some number then you say keep repeating while i is greater than 0. Then you keep incrementing i by doing i++. So essentially i keeps getting greater and never less.

Comment: Why are you trying to use parseInt in a for loop? Can you please post more code?  It's hard to tell what the issue is with what little we have.

Comment: @wanderer0810. It's pretty obvious mate.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Yep, I can't believe I missed that. How embarrassing.

Comment: @wanderer0810 lol we all have our off days mate.

Comment: Okay so by doing i-- , the text i enter is now shown (Thanks!) but I it doesnt repeat.

Comment: @Echo3000 so if you put 4. How many times does it repeat? Or not at all?

Comment: @David Kroukamp No the program crashes and I have to close it with Task Manager.